# split string with regex using a release character and separators

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse an EDI file, where the separators are `+`, `:` and `'` signs and the escape *(release)* character is `?`.
You first split into segments

```
var data = "NAD+UC+ABC2378::92++XYZ Corp.:Tel ?: ?+90 555 555 11 11:Mobile1?: ?+90 555 555 22 22:Mobile2?: ?+90 555 555 41 71+Duzce+Seferihisar / IZMIR++35460+TR"

var segments = data.Split('\'');
```

then each segment is split into segment data elements by `+`, then segment data elements are split into component data elements via `:`.

```
var dataElements = segments[0].Split('+');
```

the above sample string is not parsed correctly because of the use of release character. I have special code dealing with this, but I am thinking that this should be all doable using

```
Regex.Split(data, separator);
```

I am not familiar with Regex'es and could not find a way to do this so far.
The best I came up so far is

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(data, @"[^?]\+");
```

which omits the character before `+` sign.

```
NA
U
ABC2378::9
+XYZ Corp.:Tel ?: ?+90 555 555 11 11:Mobile1?: ?+90 555 555 22 22:Mobile2?: ?+90 555 555 41 7
Duzc
Seferihisar / IZMI
+3546
TR
```

Correct Result Should be:

```
NAD
UC
ABC2378::92

XYZ Corp.:Tel ?: ?+90 555 555 11 11:Mobile1?: ?+90 555 555 22 22:Mobile2?: ?+90 555 555 41 7
Duzce
Seferihisar / IZMIR
35460
TR
```

So the question is this doable with Regex.Split, and what should the regex separator look like.

Comment: In your sample data I don't see any `'` so how are you splitting around those ?

Comment: I did not want to include the whole file, so sample data is just one line of those segments that is already parsed.

Comment: OK. So you want to split where there is a `+` not preceded by a `?`, Right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see that you want to split around plus signs `+` only if they are not preceded *(escaped)* by a question mark `?`. This can be done using the following:

```
(?<!\?)\+
```

This matches one or more `+` signs if they are not preceded by a question mark `?`.

**Edit:** The problem or bug with the previous expression if that it doesn't handle situations like `??+` or `???+` or or `????+`, in other words it doesn't handle situations where `?`s are used to escape themselves.

We can solve this problem by noticing that if there is an odd number of `?` preceding a `+` then the last one is definitely escaping the `+` so we must not split, but if there is an even number of `?` before a plus then those cancel out each leaving the `+` so we should split around it.

From the previous observation we should come up with an expression that matches a `+` **only if** it is preceded by an **even** number of question marks `?`, and here it is:

```
(?<!(^|[^?])(\?\?)*\?)\+
```

Comment: I ran a test code, looks okay so far. Will mark it as answer when I am 100%.

Comment: Well, actually multiple adjacent separators are very common, "+++++++" is perfectly valid, and yes it should split into empty strings.

Comment: I updated the correct result string, each `+` sign should result in a new string, at least an empty string.

Comment: Should '??' be interpreted as single '?' ? IOW, is '??+' a '?' followed by a separator?

Comment: @Arkadiy yes ?? should output a single ? I was considering running a replace "??", "?" on the output string when every parsing is complete, and I really do not expect a scenario like "??+", but this is also valid, also "???+" is a valid string I guess and the last ? mark here is used as escape character.

Comment: In that case the RE would be more complex. The one given in the answer I think would interpret ??+ as '?+' literal, not '?' and separator.

Comment: @Arkadiy,@Sniffer Yes, I have not encountered a situation like "data??+data" or "data???+data" so far, (already processed thousands of messages). I know it does leave a door open for potential bugs, and I would be more than happy if you could provide the RegEx Pattern which covers this scenarios. What I can do now is replace "??" with "SOMEVERYUNIQUETEXT", before parsing data and then replace it back in the results with "??" , then when all the parsing is done, replace "??" with "?". I learned today that writing (complex for me) RegEx patterns takes a lot of experience, and I am not capable.

Comment: @Sniffer thank you Sniffer, I ran a couple of tests to make sure it works, it handles "NAD??+UC" but it does NOT handle "NAD???+UC", it fails with odd number of "?" but handles even numbers of "?" okay.

Comment: @hazimdikenl I had a huge typo mistake in my last statement, so I fixed it. Anyway Everything works now, Right ? I mean no problem whatsoever, notice that I fixed a little bug in the expression too.

Comment: @Sniffer yes, everything works great now, thank you very much. Btw, could you point me to some online RegEx learning site, that I can also experiment with. (Actually, LINQPad works fine for testing regex patterns so far.)

Comment: @hazimdikenli You are welcome, the most beloved website for learning is regular-expressions.info and you can find a few others as well as testing sites at the info page of the regex tag here at stackoverflow, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(data, @"\+");
```

would it meet the requirement??

Here is the edit for escaping the '?' before '+'.

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(data, @"(?<!\?)[\+]+");
```

The '+' end the end would match multiple consecutive occurances of seperator '+'. If you want white spaces instead.

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(data, @"(?<!\?)[\+]");
```

Comment: or may be single '+' as seperator?? and second should appear

Comment: No, if the + sign is preceded with a question mark then you should evaluate it as a + sign, not like a separator.